# Date formatting in tr Locale, Windows 7 and Linux gives 2 results

Tags: java, linux, windows-7, date-format, turkish

When the following code runs in Windows 7 it gives the month in Turkish but in Linux it gives the month in English:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMMM", new Locale("tr")).format(date);
```

- Windows 7 - 23 Ağustos
- Linux - 23 August

I want the month in Turkish in Linux too!

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not support Turkish writing on linux operating systems.
You can reference the following documentation.
[Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/locale.doc.html)

Look under...

> 2.Enabled Writing Systems for Java Foundation Classes